# Shoes not filtering using cookies

Tags: php, cookies

For some reason the code wont filter the gender `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="mascu"` or `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="feme"`

By the other hand the conditions for the ages works as expected, it have to show a picture of a shoe depending of the age range; If the age is between 30 and 39 it has to shows a pic of a sport shoe by the other hand if the range is between 40 and 60 shows it has to show a formal shoes, but the problem is it shows both sport shoes female and male version alike and the same happens with formal shoes.

zapatos.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zapatos Hombre o Mujer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="zapatosDatabase.php">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="nombreForm">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Edad</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name=edadForm value="">
        <br>
        <br> 
        <label>sexo</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sexoForm" value="mascu">
        <label>Masculino</label>
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="sexoForm" value="feme">
        <label>Femenino</label>
        <br>
        <br> 
        <input type="submit" name="enviarValorForm" value="Enviar!">
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

zapatosDatabase.php

```
<?php

$nombreValor = $_POST["nombreForm"];
$sexoValor = $_POST["sexoForm"];
$edadValor = $_POST["edadForm"];

setcookie("nombre_cookie",$nombreValor);
setcookie("sexo_cookie",$sexoValor);
setcookie("edad_cookie",$edadValor);

$_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=$sexoValor;
$_COOKIE['edad_cookie']=$edadValor;


//Masculino
  if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="mascu" && $edadValor >= 30 && $edadValor <= 39 ){
    echo "Zapatillas deportivos masculino";
    echo "<img src='./img/deportivas_mascu.jpg'>";
    }else if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="mascu" && $edadValor >= 40 && $edadValor <= 60 ){
    echo "Zapatos formales masculino";
    echo "<img src='./img/zapatos_mascu.jpg'>";
    }else{
    echo "Cookie $nombreValor $sexoValor $edadValor no esta creada";
    }

// Femenino
if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="feme" && $edadValor >= 30 && $edadValor <= 39 ){
    echo "Zapatillas deportivos femeninas";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<img src='./img/deportivas_feme.jpg'>";
  }else if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="feme" && $edadValor >= 40 && $edadValor <= 60 ){
    echo "Zapatos formales femeninas";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<img src='./img/zapatos_feme.jpg'>";
    }else{
      echo "Cookie $nombreValor $sexoValor $edadValor no esta creada";
    }

?>
```

Comment: `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="mascu") {}`<-- Two equal signs are for comparison. One for assignment.

Comment: Yes... so...  that is the reason of two IF statements one for `$_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="mascu")` and the other for `$_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="feme"` if the first one not meet the criteria have to execute the second one or viceversa

Comment: You set `$_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']` to "mascu" with `$_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']="mascu"` which is always true. You need to use two equal signs `if ($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie'] == "mascu") {}`

Comment: No... still shows both shoes male and female

Comment: Please update your question code.

Comment: You have much more assignements in the if statements!

Answer (score 0):

According to you code snippet I found that you are trying to compare value with another one inside if and elseif condition. But in your code you have used single equal **(=)** that is not logical.
For comparing you should always double equal **(==)** sign. I also want to mention that single equal **(=)** is for assigning some value in variable and double equal **(==)** is for comparing.
So , you should modify your code and then run it. After that, you will work on error or logical issues as well.

Comment: Or tripple equal (===) for type safeness.

Comment: Tested both versions:
double == `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="mascu") {}`  `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="feme" {}` and triple === `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']==="mascu") {}` `if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']==="feme" {}` dont work both versions.

The output is the same, shows both gender shoes:
`https://i.imgur.com/jX3sxCS.png`

Answer (score 0):

Solved

zapatosDatabase.php

```
<?php

$nombreValor = $_POST["nombreForm"];
$sexoValor = $_POST["sexoForm"];
$edadValor = $_POST["edadForm"];

setcookie("nombre_cookie",$nombreValor);
setcookie("sexo_cookie",$sexoValor);
setcookie("edad_cookie",$edadValor);

$_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=$sexoValor;
$_COOKIE['edad_cookie']=$edadValor;



if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="mascu" && $edadValor >= 30 && $edadValor <= 39){ //Deportivas masculinas 30 a 39
  echo "<img src='./img/deportivas_mascu.jpg'>";
}else if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="mascu" && $edadValor >= 40 && $edadValor <= 60){ //Zapatos masculinos 40 a 60
  echo "<img src='./img/zapatos_mascu.jpg'>";
  }

if($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="feme" && $edadValor >= 30 && $edadValor <= 39){ //Deportivas femeninas edad 30 a 39
  echo "<img src='./img/deportivas_feme.jpg'>";
}else if ($_COOKIE['sexo_cookie']=="feme" && $edadValor >= 40 && $edadValor <= 60){ //Zapatos femeninos edad 40 a 60
  echo "<img src='./img/zapatos_feme.jpg'>";
  }
```